# CakePHP prepopulate form with data from a link

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, post, get

Assume I'm in my `items` controller.

Ok say I am in my `view` action (the url would be something like `/items/view/10012?date=2013-09-30`) which lists a list of items that belongs to a client on a given date.

I want to link to add a new item. I would use the htmlhelper like so:
`echo $this->Html('action'=>'add');`

In my `add` action I have a form which has fields like `client_id` and `item_date`.

When I'm in my `view` action I know these values as I am viewing the items for a specific client on a specific date. I want to pass these variables to my `add` action so it will prefill those fields on the form.

If I add a query string in my `link` (`'?' => array('client_id'=>$client_id)`) it breaks the add action as it will give an error if the request is not POST. If I use a `form->postLink` I get another error as the add action's POST data must only be used for adding the record, not passing data to prefill the form.

I basically want to make my link on the `view` page pass those 2 variables to the `add` action in the controller so I can define some variables to prefill the form. Is there a way to do this?

Here is my `add` controller code. It may differ in content a bit from my question above as I have tried to simplify the question a bit but the concept should still apply.

```
public function add(){
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Holding->create();
        if ($this->Holding->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Holding has been saved.'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-success'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your holding.'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-danger'));
    }
    $this->set('accounts', $this->Holding->Account->find('list'));
        $sedol_list = $this->Holding->Sedol->find('all', array(
            'fields' => array(
                'id', 'sedol_description'
                ),
            'recursive' => 0,
            'order'  => 'description'
            )
        );
        $this->set('sedols', Hash::combine($sedol_list, '{n}.Sedol.id', '{n}.Sedol.sedol_description') );
}
```

Comment: You are on the right track. But you should post the relevant controller code here. There you most likely have an error of some sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use proper Cake URL parameters?

```
echo $this->Html->link('Add Item', array(
    'action' => 'add',
    $client_id,
    $item_date
));
```

This will give you a much nicer URL like:

http://www.example.com/items/add/10012/2013-09-30

And then in your controller, you modify the function to receive those parameters:

```
public function add($client_id, $item_date) {

    // Prefill the form on this page by manually setting the values
    // in the request data array. This is what Cake uses to populate
    // the form inputs on your page.
    if (empty($this->request->data)) {

        $this->request->data['Item']['client_id'] = $client_id;
        $this->request->data['Item']['item_date'] = $item_date;

    } else {

        // In here process the form data normally from when the
        // user has submitted it themselves...

    }

}
```

Comment: Perfect. I knew there should be a way. This is the right way to do it. Thanks a lot.